# How can I predict customer lifetime value in 12 months?

Tags: python, customer-lifetime-value

I was trying to predict 'customer lifetime value' but only for the first 12 months of him/her in the platform I work for. However, most models, such as Pareto/NBD, are good in order to assess the real lifetime value, not only for this short period.

First, I thought about using lifetimes package in Python, but only filtering the twelve first payments of each customer. But when I try to use the predict function, I can't make this sort of control (limit to 12 months after the subscription).

Is there any way of doing this? Any package in which this is possible?

Comment: You should be able to compute E[y(T2-T1) | y(T1)] from the Pareto/NBD or BG/NBD.  Did you try that?